# Git - read only local copy

Tags: git

I have a local copy of a repo that runs on a production server.

Some people keep changing minor files on this local copy but I find it unacceptable considering this is a production copy, and considering we forbid changes directly in the master branch (PRs are mandatory).

I would like to make that local copy read_only, but those files still need to be written when we use git pull. if I perform `chmod -R -w .` i understand that git pull will not be possible.

What is the best way to protect this copy from local edit but to keep it possible by making git pull?

Comment: Use a dedicated user for those files, don't give to any one access to this user.
Add a sudo to git pull for this user to anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this question is asking: "how to make a directory non-writable by non-sudoers account, but must be writable with `git pull` command"

note that in this answer I'm not going to type `sudo`, just use common sense in which commands needs to be sudo'ed

There's no documentation on how to accomplish it on git (as I know). But you can always do a little hack. The basic idea is as follow:

- make a new user (let's call it userX) or use existing account
- make the directory owner user X (ex: `chown -R userX:userX .`),
- then make file permission to only allow user X to write (ex: `chmod -R 775 .`),
- then implement some method to execute `git pull` with user X, without having to log into user X's account, and without using sudo (described below).

### alternative 1:

set `git` binary's setuid (4000) special permission, and change its owner to X

- `chmod 4775 /usr/bin/git`
- `chown userX:root /usr/bin/git`
  this will make git's binary to be owned by user X, and owned by group root (unchanged), and when git binary is executed, it will be executed as user X rather than current user

### alternative 2:

set `git` binary's setgid (2000) special permission, and change its group owner to X

- `chmod 2755 /usr/bin/git`
- `chown root:userX /usr/bin/git`
  this will make git's binary to be owned by root (unchanged), and owned by group userX, and when git binary is executed, it will be executed as (group) user X rather than current user

read more about setuid and setgid:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html
- https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits
- https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-do-i-set-up-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits-on-linux/

### alternative 3:

- assuming your repository exist in `/var/www/html/myrepo` (default)
- run apache (or any web server that you like), make it listen to some unused port for example port 8081 (make sure that port is not exposed to internet for security reason, ex: filtered by firewall or it just bound to `localhost` rather than `0.0.0.0` or public ip address)
- assuming your apache user is `www-data` (default)
- `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/myrepo`
- `chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/myrepo`
- create a vhost in apache, with document root pointing to some directory (ex: `/home/userX/www`
- create php file in `/home/userX/www/index.php` containing

```php
<?php
chdir("/var/www/html/myrepo");
exec("git pull origin branchnamehere");
```

- when you need to do a `git pull`, just run command: `wget http://localhost:8081`

## Explanation

### alternative 1 and 2:

- you make the directory that contain your repository to be writable only by user X
- setuid or setgid special permission:

```
When set-user identification (setuid) permission is set on an executable file, 
a process that runs this file is granted access based on the owner of the file
(usually root), rather than the user who is running the executable file. 
This special permission allows a user to access files and directories that 
are normally only available to the owner. 
For example, the setuid permission on the passwd command makes it possible 
for a user to change passwords...
```

- so, you set git's binary to be executed as user X, therefore `git pull` command CAN write in the directory, but normal user CANNOT write in the directory

### alternative 3:

- you make the directory that contain your repository to be writable only by apache's user (ex: `www-data`)
- you do not need to setuid or setgid special permission here
- when a HTTP request is handled by webserver (ex: apache), it will be run as webserver's user (ex: `www-data`)
- in index page, there is a php command to execute command in shell containing `git pull` command
- also make sure to set `/home/userX/www/index.php` to 555 or not writable (so non sudoers cannot write to it)

## Comparison

- alternative 1 and 2 can be dangerous since we're changing git binary permission, so an update to git might broke things
- alternative 3 might introduce overhead in computing resource since we need to run an additional web server

## Other idea

- change owner of your repo to user X `chown -R userX:userX /var/www/html/myrepo`
- change permission to be writable only by owner `chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/myrepo`
- make bash script `/home/me/pullme.sh`, containing:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
# change directory to your repository
cd /var/www/html/myrepo
# execute git pull
git pull origin branchnamehere
```

- make your bash script owned by user X `chown userX:userX /home/me/pullme.sh`
- set the script's setuid `chmod 4755 /home/me/pullme.sh`
- when you want to pull, just run `sh /home/me/pullme.sh`